# How to send transaction from metamask wallet to backend node js

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js, metamask

i am building simple dapp application where i want to verify something and then only make contract interaction but right now i am struggling to put a middleware which will act like user will make txn through metamask and then this txn or something will go to backend server on any language probably node js , and i will do some checking and if all good then Send it to block chain.

Any suggestion?

Right now its all in react Frontend and metamask browser extension.. and i can not make client side code restricted
And i can not ask for private key even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible by design. A transaction needs to be signed by the sender's private key. So unless the users are willing to give you their private key (so that you could sign the transaction for them on the backend), you'll need to change your approach.

If you need to allow interaction with the contract only to users authorized by your app, the contract needs to hold the list of authorized addresses. And the list can be updated by your app (that holds the private key to the `owner` address). Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    address public owner = address(0x123);
    mapping(address => bool) public isAuthorized;

    function setAuthorized(address _address, bool _isAuthorized) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, 'Only the contract owner can set authorized addresses');
        isAuthorized[_address] = _isAuthorized;
    }

    function foo() external {
        require(isAuthorized[msg.sender], 'Only authorized addresses can execute this function');
        // ...
    }
}
```